# What should be done when tags and the FAQ conflict?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, off-topic

Recently two of my questions were closed as off-topic (one on Stack Overflow and the other on Programmers SE) and I was referred to the FAQ. The problem is, both questions were similar in nature to questions asked with the same tag (on SO, the tag was [career](/questions/tagged/career)). So my question is: what should be done in this case?

Comment: Where are the links?

Comment: @random FWIW http://stackoverflow.com/q/4234036/464629 this is the overflow q

Comment: Oh come on now, why the down-vote.

Comment: That SO example is lacking code for a programming Q&A

Comment: @random you are right, however as I explained I was going by tag. Now I know that was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take heed to the FAQ.

Questions asked and tagged a long time ago, especially months back, haven't all caught up to being closed as off-topic or deleted outright if/when the FAQ is updated to better articulate the focus and topic of the website.

Just because it was asked before, continues to live by a hair's halitosis and doesn't jive with the FAQ as it is now, doesn't mean a question posted today will come through as turkey clean.

Comment: Thanks. I am new here and was seriously puzzled by the trigger happy behavior. I am sure this happens with other new users too. Perhaps this can be be made easier by declaring tags which conflict with FAQ as invalid tags or something.

Comment: @Gaurav, cleanup of "bad tags" is actually already in progress.